# What is this fossilized claw found in a Belgian forest?

Tags: species-identification, palaeontology, bone-biology, bone, fossil

What is this fossilized claw found in a Belgian forest? It is 14.5 cm long and 2.5 cm in diameter.

[image: whatisthis]
[image]

Comment: What are its dimensions?

Comment: Why do you say it is fossilized?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the proximal end of a rib of a large mammal (cow, horse, deer). Without information about how large it is, it is not possible to get closer to an identification. It's not a claw and very likely not a fossil. It just looks old and dirty.

Here's a horse rib cage (from https://www.rodnikkel.com/content/saddle-tree-blog-from-shop-and-desk/the-rib-cage/):

[image]

Ribs in the 4-7 range seem to be a good match for shape but not as much for roundness.

Comment: It is 14.5 cm long and 2.5 cm in diameter

Comment: This isn't my area, but how can you tell that it isn't any other elongate structure from a large mamal? For example, why isn't it a horn/antler?

Answer (score 1):

That's the distal end of an antler of some deer. You can tell because the texture is smooth and glossy, all wrong for a rib, and has that flange at the end which looks very different from the uncinate processes you see in some ribs but looks a lot like the flanges you see on some deer antlers. The more rugose, "veiny" texture near the base is also typical of deer antlers. My guess is that it's either a red deer (*Cervus elaphus*) or roe deer (*Capreolus capreolus*) antler fragment.

It's not a claw, because it lacks a clear flexor tubercle, articular facet, etc.

[image]

The cross-section is also very typical of a deer antler. This is what a deer antler looks like in cross-section.